# In python, how can I make an if statement for each word in user input. Example in actual post

Tags: python

I'm making a bible verse look up. The idea is to use bible gateway website and use python to replace numbers in the url automatically to send straight to the website page. So, if the url is: http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=|John|+|4|%3A|1||6|&version=ESV

How can I make the numbers and name in between the "| |" variables so that it can take user input?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are asking about [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting), python 2 example:

```
>>> url = "http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=|John|+|4|%3A|1||{number}|&version=ESV"
>>> number = raw_input('Enter number: ')
Enter number: 10
>>> url.format(number=number)
'http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=|John|+|4|%3A|1||10|&version=ESV'
```

Pay attention to the `{number}` placeholder in the url.

Note that if you are on python3, it would be `input()` instead of `raw_input()`.

Comment: yeah,just use string format